# ¿Cuál es el significado de “de su corrido”?

Tags: expresiones, significado

Oí un programa del radio como siguiente:

> En XX (una ruta de una montaña), se encuentra el tramo más difícil **de su corrido**.

Segun el diccionario [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/corrido), *de corrido = rápido, sin interrupción.*

¿Pero es correcta que pon “su” entre ellos?
¿O, lo oí mal y no es “su” sino otra palabra? ¿Será “del sur corrido”?

Comment: solo se me ocurre que sea un programa americano, los programas de radio y televisión americanos tienen un horrible manejo del lenguaje.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal y como la escribes, la frase no tiene sentido.

Efectivamente, [*de corrido*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AzW0XsA) es una expresión que el DLE define como *1. Con presteza y sin entorpecimientos*. Sin embargo, en este contexto no tiene demasiado sentido.

Por contra, lo que sí parece bastante plausible es que esté hablando del ***recorrido***, que no es otra cosa que el itinerario o ruta:

> En XX (una ruta de una montaña), se encuentra el tramo más difícil **de su recorrido**.

Por tanto, aquí te está diciendo que la parte XX de la ruta es la más complicada.

Answer (score 1):

Si bien *de su corrido* no existe, sí existe *de su corrida* para hacer alusión a la ruta.

---

Nótese que este uso podría no ser idiomático en otras regiones.

Comment: De hecho si cambias "corrido" por "corrida" la oración funciona perfecto, al menos en Chile.

Comment: @Rodrigo Mi punto, justamente.